# set up a zend framework project in XAMPP

Tags: zend-framework

My Xampp version is 1.6.7. I want to set up a Zendframework project in my local system. I have downloaded Zendframework and extracted it and copied into C:\xampp\php (My zendframework foldeer is ZendFramework-1.11.4). In my php.ini i have set my include path to

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\pear\;C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework-1.11.4\library\"
```

Also i have set Environment variable path to `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework-1.11.4\bin;C:\xampp\php;`

I have copied the whole zendframework folder to `my xamp/htdocs/projects/`
Then in my command i have run

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zf.bat create project ZendFramework-1.11.4
```

But i got many error.
Please give me a detail replay. Also is there is any good tutorial

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are new to zend framework, hava a look at this series of tutorials http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vhxo2oL70E , there is a tutorial on the cli tool too.

Answer (score 2):

> I have copied the whole zendframework folder to my
>   xamp/htdocs/projects/ Then in my command i have run

You don't have to do that, download the minimal version of Zend framework and try to run:

```
C:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\bin\zf.bat create project myprojectname
```

Where "myprojectname" is the name of your project.

The enviromental variables and the include_path look good. Just do the changes I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `Zend` folder (from the extract), in your `library` folder of your project it should normally work.

And xampp comes with default zend-framework (1.8 I guess), and the zend library is usually at `C:\xampp\php\pear\zend` (better replaced with `Zend` folder from extract.)

Also there's `zf.bat` and `zf.php` in `php` folder, which (if set to env path) needs to be replaced with the one that comes with zend-framewrok.